# How to fix "'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency"?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I have these two functions (which compile without errors):

```swift
func hasLocalChanges() -> Bool {
    return false
}

func hasRemoteChanges() async -> Bool {
    return await Task{ true }.value
}
```

Now, let's say I want to introduce a third function which will look like this:

```swift
func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
    return self.hasLocalChanges() || await self.hasRemoteChanges()
}
```

Then this function will give me a compiler error saying:

```text
'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency
```

But why is that?

I can resolve the error by swapping the operands …

```swift
func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
    return await self.hasRemoteChanges() || self.hasLocalChanges()
}
```

…, which, again, will make the code compile without errors.

But I really want to make use of lazy evaluation and have the asynchronous function be executed last. So the only way to achieve that would be to say …

```swift
func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
    if !self.hasLocalChanges() {
        return await self.hasRemoteChanges()
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

…, which seems a little cumbersome.

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting that error in the first place?

Comment: Or you could write it as `func hasChanges() async -> Bool { self.hasLocalChanges() ? true : await self.hasRemoteChanges() }`

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. The Stackoverflow format is Question+Answers. Upvote/Accept the answer that gave you the solution, instead.

Comment: Wanted to post this as a comment, but SO doesn't allow code blocks in comments.

Comment: Understood. But, as weird as it sounds, to preserve the Q&A format and not invalidate existing answers, you should just post your own answer to your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) From my perspective, it's not a big deal, but something to keep in mind for future reference.

Comment: Alright, makes sense, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `||` is actually a function that wants the right hand side to look like `rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool` (vs. e.g `rhs: @autoclosure () async throws -> Bool`)

See the source here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e6cbf5483237aa593bdbafb6c7db7ebcb2d0e26a/stdlib/public/core/Bool.swift#L320

When you move the await first, it resolves into a boolean and then `self.hasLocalChanges()` is a non async `() throws -> Bool`

Examples that compile below

```swift
    func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
        return or( a: await hasRemoteChanges(), b: hasLocalChanges())
    }
    
    // This is pretty much what `||` looks like today
    func or(a: Bool, b: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) -> Bool {
        return a ? true : try b()
    }
```

```swift
    func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
        return await or( a: hasLocalChanges(), b: await hasRemoteChanges())
    }
    
    // This is what an `async` friendly `||` could look like. 
    // Note that the caller would need to await the result.
    func or(a: Bool, b: @autoclosure () async throws -> Bool) async -> Bool {
        return a ? true : try! await b()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve also just encountered this and was looking to do exactly what you were: avoid calling the async func if my other value is true. Going off of what aciniglio said, I believe you could avoid the `or` func and keep this inline by having something like:

```
func hasChanges() async -> Bool {
    return self.hasLocalChanges() ? true : await self.hasRemoteChanges()
}
```

This can also work with an `if` of course, which is what I was trying to do, like:

```
func doSomething() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        if self.hasLocalChanges() ? true : await self.hasRemoteChanges() {
            print("Something")
        }
    }
}
```